# Is oncontextmenu cross browser?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

```
window.oncontextmenu = function() {
    return false;
};
```

Will this work on all major browsers such that the right click will not be initiated?

Comment: No need to be a meany face ]:

Comment: Not everything is intrinsically good or intrinsically bad.  Disabling the context menu may be just what the OP needs for the situation.  I've done this to provide a custom menu for some elements.  You can't make blanket statements without context.

Comment: @Dennis you're right, we don't know what David is doing so snarky comments are a bit premature. But 95% of the people who ask this on SO want to block the right click on a normal web site, which *is* a terrible thing to do. Still, I didn't mean to be mean :)

Comment: A kiosk is one such legitimate situation and is exactly what led me here. I'm trying to build in as many redundant safety features as possible.

Comment: Another legitimate use: Games.

Comment: For my project we use an embedded web browser control to display text with mark-up, nothing in the right click menu will do anything sensible. Turning it off is the only sensible thing to do.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

See [this quirksmode page](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/contextmenu.html) for a detailed compatibility table.

Comment: +1 for being professional enough to separate helpful content (answer) from opinion (comment), even though I think the latter is more important in this particular case :)

Answer (score 2):

[QuirksMode](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/contextmenu.html) has a comprehensive chart of support for the event.  You can use it to decide if it meets your needs depending on browsers you support.